# Front camera issue in miui 8 using bit6 cordova plugin during video call

Tags: android, cordova, camera

Right now I'm making one application which uses bit6 cordova plugin
for video calling and in my xiaomi device I already have granted permission to access my camera though I can not access my front camera but I can access front camera in other android devices, So let me know if there is any special requirements for that.

Below is my permission list in xml file:

```
 <platform name="android">
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />  -->
        <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"></uses-feature>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    </config-file>
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="WebSocket">
            <param name="android-package" value="com.ququplay.websocket.WebSocket" />
        </feature>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```